# How to save to PHP file with encoding - in PHP or JS

Tags: php, javascript, character-encoding

I can't find any clue how to save textarea etc. to .php file on the server with special encoding. Is exist any library/framwework method/class? I hope that you will understand me, what I mean.

ps. Textarea save *.php on the server :)

Comment: Your tags are ambiguous.  Do you mean character-encoding like UTF-8 or do you mean encoding like encryption?

Comment: I'm sorry i do it so fast ;/ i mean UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). The encoding on the created file should be the same as the encoding on the POST data.

**Warning**: what you're trying to do looks dangerous! It has the potential to allow anyone to create and run arbitrary PHP code on your server!

Comment: ok, I will try. Yes, i know it but i have to figuread how to secure this.